# How to select a workout plan?

Tags: workout-routines

I am 25 years old. I am 6 feet and 2 inches. I weigh 111 kgs. or 244 pounds. I have been exercising on and off for 2 years. I have lost 30 kgs in the mean time.

Right now I can run fartleks for 30 minutes covering about 5 kilometers (yeah, I know that's still woefully bad). I can bench press about 50 kilograms (110 pounds) (3 sets of each type - I do 3 types - Each set is of 10 reps). I lift similar weight in my squats.

So, with this type of strength and stamina, what would be the best workout for me ?

There are so many on the internet. It is really confusing. What are the metrics on which I must choose a workout plan from the internet ?

I want to lose weight and develop super human strength. I don't really care about beautiful muscles. I want to be strong enough to fight bears - not that I would. I think they are magnificent creatures.

Comment: To lose fat,  continue with your diet, 30  kgs over 2 years is a good result. As to strength - go  with the  Eric Kaufman's answer for at least  half a year.

Answer (score 3):

It gets referenced a lot, but for good reason: check out [Mark Rippetoe's Starting Strength](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982522738). The book and the program is, from my prospective, the most effective short and long term path to human strength. Whether you decide to be a Rippetoe fan for the rest of your life is up to you, but the things you learn from it and the path it puts you on really can be life changing.

The specific components, summarized, in Starting Strength consists of this:

- Compound barbell lifts. Back squats, overhead press, deadlift, cleans, barbell rows.
- Effective body weight. Dips, pullups.
- Prioritizing strength over body building.
- Prioritizing effectiveness of exercises, and accurate form.
- Protein intake.

I would really recommend you follow the Starting Strength path almost exactly. Everyone wants to futz with a program and add things in: don't. Do it for six months at least by the book.

Comment: And after those six months on starting strength, pick up Rippetoe's Practical Programming for Strength Training, and figure out where to go from there. www.amazon.com/Practical-Programming-Strength-Training-Rippetoe/dp/0982522754